# For adding custom POS data to SpaCy tagger - what format should full sentence examples be in?

Tags: spacy

Follow up question to [Train spaCy's existing POS tagger with my own training examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779217/train-spacys-existing-pos-tagger-with-my-own-training-examples/56780823#56780823)

I really like aab's answer

"The English model is trained on PTB tags, not UD tags. spacy's tag map gives you a pretty good idea about the correspondences, but the PTB tagset is more fine-grained that the UD tagset:

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/en/tag_map.py

Skip the tag_map-related code (the PTB -> UD mapping is already there in the model), change your tags in your data to PTB tags (NN, NNS, JJ, etc.), and then this script should run. (You'll still have to check whether it performs well, of course.)

In general, it's better to provide training examples with full phrases or sentences, since that's what spacy will be tagging in real usage like your test sentence."

And am wondering what format to store and provide full phrase or sentence training examples in.